# Laravel 4 Package updation without to affect my manual changes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am novice in Laravel 4. I have a doubt regarding a package. I am using a sentry package and already made some changes in it according to my requirements and it is working well. But have a doubt, when sentry will release some new features and I want to add them in my app **without to affect my previous manually made changes in it**

Please guide me on this, How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off by saying that in most cases, it is a very bad idea to change to code of a package. Laravel provides an [easy way](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages) to naturally override some of the parts of a package (especially stuff like views and assets)

Now if that's not working out for you there are two methods to change the package code and keep your updates.

1. **Fork the package.** If you fork the git repository you basically have your own version of the package. That means you have to handle updates yourself and also means you have control over your code.
2. **Use --prefer-source.** Require the package with `composer require vendor/package --prefer-source`. So it will clone the git repository instead of just downloading a copy. That way, when you change the code and then do `composer update` it will ask you if you want to keep local changes. BUT: everytime the   you update the package you will have to make sure that in the end you keep your changes and also have all the changes of the new version...

I highly recommend you first think about if you can solve your problem without changing package code. Maybe an option would be writing your own class that extends the packages class.
If you want more advice on this ask a new question or update this existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Never touch the vendor directory. app directory is your playground.

If you made the changes in app directory, you are good to go. Composer update will not affect your app code.